# Find a function with right and left limits on $[0,1]$ and discontinuities at $\{ \dfrac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find a function with right and left limits on $[0,1]$, wherever they are defined, and discontinuities at $\{ \dfrac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

I have
$f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x = \dfrac{1}{n} \textrm{ for } n \in \mathbb{N} \\
x & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Attempts:

1. Let $x \in (0,1].$ Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $(x_m)$ be a sequence in $[0,1] \setminus \{x\}$ converging to $x$. We can find a neighbourhood $B$ of $x$ containing $x$ but no points of the form $\dfrac{1}{n}$. Then, since $(x_m) \rightarrow x$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n \geq N$, $x_n$ lies in $B$. Thus, for any $n \geq N$, $f(x_n)=x_n$. Thus $\displaystyle \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}f(x_m)=x.$
2. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Set $c=\dfrac{1}{n}.$ Take $d = \dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}$. Then for $|x-\dfrac{1}{n}|<d$, we have that $x \in \left(\dfrac{1}{n+1},\dfrac{2}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right).$ Note that, for $n>1$, \begin{align*} &\dfrac{2}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}< \dfrac{1}{n-1} \\
   &\impliedby \dfrac{n+2}{n(n+1)} < \dfrac{1}{n-1} \\
   &\impliedby (n-1)(n+2) < n(n+1) \\
   &\impliedby n^2 + n - 2 < n^2 + n \\
   &\impliedby -2 < 0.  \end{align*}

So for any $x \in [0,1]$ with $|x-c|<d$, $$|f(x) - \dfrac{1}{n}|<|\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}| < \max\{1/n,1/(n+1)\} = 1/n.$$ Stuck!

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by right and left limits for the second case? Right and left limits to what point? What second case?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited the post for more details. I apologise for not having this detail in the first version itself.

Comment: Showing the right limit at $x=0$ exists would require a little bit more work (not much though, just an extra case would do I think)

Comment: In attempt 1, I'm not sure why you mention $n$ and use $\frac{1}{n}$ in the way $\epsilon$ is typically used. It seems unecessary, like you would like to get $\frac{1}{n}$ into the answer, but in the wrong fashion.

You write that $f(x_n)=x_n$ without justifying it. You need to say that any $x\in (0,1]$ is bounded away from the nearest $\frac{1}{n}$, ie. there's an interval around any $x\in (0,1]$ containing no $\frac{1}{n}$ (except $x$ if it is such a point), so when a sequence $a_k$ gets close enough to $x$, we have $f(a_k)=a_k$.

Comment: Thanks a lot toe-pose! I finally understand how to write it up. I was slightly averse to just writing the words, without some explicit $N$ or something. Thank you! I can understand it now ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fine example here. You just need to clarify the details a little.

The crucial thing is that each $\frac{1}{n}$ is separated from $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $\frac{1}{n-1}$ by some positive distance. This means for any $x\in (0,1]$, regardless of being some $\frac{1}{n}$ or not, there is a neighbourhood $B$ containing $x$ but containing no other point of the form $\frac{1}{n'}$ for $n'\in \mathbb{N}$. Thus for all points $y\in B$ (except $x$ itself in the case $x=\frac{1}{n}$), we have $f(y)=y$.

Therefore, any sequence $a_k$ that approaches $x$ from below (or above) eventually lies inside $B$. ie. for $k$ large enough we always have $f(a_k)=a_k$ and thus the sequence $f(a_k)$ approaches $x$ as well. This is exactly what it means for $f$ to have left (and right) limits everywhere on $(0,1]$.

The point $x=0$ is trickier, (since any neighbourhood around $0$ contains infinitely many points of the form $\frac{1}{n}$) but you can show that any sequence $a_k$ approaching $x$ from above also has $f(a_k)\rightarrow 0$, since once $a_k$ is within $\epsilon$ of $0$ we have $f(a_k)\leq \epsilon$.

And it is clear from all this that we have discontinuities at each $\frac{1}{n}$, since if $a_k\rightarrow\frac{1}{n}$ then $f(a_k)\rightarrow\frac{1}{n}$ yet $f(\frac{1}{n})=0\not=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! I tried to flesh out the details for the $x \in (0,1]$ case. I added them to the OP with label Attempt 1. Could you check it if possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The function you defined works. In order to prove discontinuity, you have to think about the definition of discontinuity: We say a function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = f(c)$.

Now take $c=\frac{1}{n}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. From the function you defined, $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = c \neq 0 = f(c)$. In conclusion, the limit exists, but the function is discontinuous in those points.

Comment: Thank you! I can understand the discontinuity part, but I am unsure about how to show the limit exists. If I do the following, would it be correct? Let $c \in [0.1] \setminus \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\} $, $x_n$ be a sequence in $[0.1]$ converging to $c$. Then I can pick $N$ so large that $x_n$ is not of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n \geq N$. Hence, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = c.$

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood your question. Take $1/n$ and let $d=1/n-1/(n+1)$, in the interval $(1/n-d, 1/n+d)\\1/n, \ f(x)=x$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1/n}f(x)=1/n$. Does this help? I can edit my answer.

Comment: Hi! Thank you. I understand the argument, but could you tell me about the part when $f(x)=x$ for all $x \in (1/n -d, 1/n+d)$? I understand that $1/n-d = 1/(n+1)$ and $1/n+d=2/n - 1/(n+1)$. Could you please explain how there's no $x$ of the form $1/m$ in the interval? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @Balkys: It suffices to show that $\frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n-1}$ for all $n>1.$

Comment: Thank you! I completely understand it now

Comment: You have to do that by induction. Prove it for a base case, say $n=2$, suppose it holds for $n$, and using that, you prove it for $n+1$. Are you aware of such proofs?

Comment: @Sergio: No need for induction, actually. It can be proved explicitly, since $n>n-\frac{1}{n}>0$ can be directly proved for any integer $n>0,$ whence the desired inequality readily follows.

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes! You are right!

Comment: @Sergio: I have used your approach in the OP. If you have time, can you let me know if it's correct? I got stuck at the last part

Comment: @Balkys I would tackle the finish of the proof like this: Fix $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta=\min\{d, \epsilon\}$, then $\lvert x - 1/n \rvert < \delta$. If $d \geq \epsilon$, then we are in the section of the domain where the $f(x)=x$, and hence $\lvert x - 1/n \rvert < \delta = \epsilon$. If $d < \epsilon$, then we choose an $x$ that will take us to such area, and therefore, $\lvert x - 1/n \rvert < d < \epsilon$. Does that help?